# How to get number of days between two dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to get number of days between two dates using below function

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# Creating a function that returns the number of days
def calculate_days(date):
    today = pd.Timestamp('today')
    return today - date

# Apply the function to the column date
df['days'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: calculate_days(x))
```

The results looks like this

> 153 days 10:16:46.294037

but I want it to say **153**. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For performance you can subtract values without `apply` for avoid loops use [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from rigth side:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['days'] = df['date'].rsub(pd.Timestamp('today')).dt.days
```

What working like:

```
df['days'] = (pd.Timestamp('today') - df['date']).dt.days
```

If want use your solution:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

def calculate_days(date):
    today = pd.Timestamp('today')
    return (today - date).days

df['days'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: calculate_days(x))
```

Or:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

def calculate_days(date):
    today = pd.Timestamp('today')
    return (today - date)

df['days'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: calculate_days(x)).dt.days
```

Comment: I tried the shorter code ```df['days'] = df['date'].sub(pd.Timestamp('today')).dt.days``` but got the error ``TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'``

Comment: @ShadowWalker _ there is used `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` ? Btw, what is your pandas version?

Comment: I corrected a typo but the result has negative values. I tried changing to ``pd.Timestamp('today').sub(df['date']).dt.days`` but got an error **Timestamp has no attribute sub**

Comment: @ShadowWalker - Sorry, it was my typo, need `rsub`, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

a) pandas

```
(pd.Timestamp("today") - df.date).days
```

b) this numpy build function allows you to select a weekmask

```
 np.busday_count(df.date.date(), pd.Timestamp("today").date(), weekmask=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```